# Nonce of AES-GCM generated by Counters

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, nonce, aes-gcm

i am trying to generate the nonce for AES-GCM. I know people usually generate it by Counters and LFSRs. I am confused about the meaning of Counters. Is that means Counter (CTR)? Why it can generate unique nonce?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you do AES-GCM on linux? Which program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counters are storing values and have usually clear, set, and increment functions. A counter can be implemented in software very easily by using an integer with enough size or using a library like Java `BigInteger` or Gnu/GMP for C/C++.

- `clear()` makes the all bits zero: `unsigned int counter=0`
- `set(y)` set the counter value to `y` : `counter = y`
- `increment()` increase the current value by 1; `counter++`

For GCM one needs 32 bits counter and a total 128-bit for the CTR mode's counter with the 96-bit nonce.

Take a 128-bit unsigned integer and init to zero. Then [GCM](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf) will use it like
$ J_0 = IV || 0^{31} ||1 $
so during the implementation, you need to take a copy of the counter, shift 32 to left, and OR with `0x01`.